# App crash after doing the minified build release when install on device

Tags: android, vue.js, nativescript

I made the release of my nativescript app in the following way:

```
tns build android --bundle --clean --env.uglify --env.aot --release --key-store-path <path>.jks --key-store-password password --key-store-alias appName --key-store-alias-password password
```

In the `app.gradle` I have the following settings:

```
android {
...
buildTypes {
    release {
      minifyEnabled true

      shrinkResources true

      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile(
              'proguard-android-optimize.txt'),
              'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
...
}
```

I generate an apk file when I install on a device, crash it and does not open, showing the next message
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P096I.jpg)

But if I set minifyEnabled and shrinkResources to false in my app.gradle, the app runs normally, but I need my minified apk. Any suggestions?

Comment: You need modify your proguard rules. Hard to say without any error msg but if your'e using some libs, they often provides required config.

Comment: Can you check in logcat and post the errors?